# Canvas, moving objects, clearRect in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Basically, my problem is that I cant understand why function `clearRect` which I use in code does not clean rectangles (For making them to move i used `setinterval` function). I have rectangles which are moving.

In Set Interval function you can see `context.clearRect(0, 0, context.elem.width, context.elem.height);` which I tried to put before the loop(did not work) and in the loop (the same :( ). Can to fix this?! Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
window.onload = function () {

    function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.fill = fill;
    }

    // get canvas element.
    var elem = document.getElementById('paper');
    context = elem.getContext('2d');
    //var container = {x:100, y:100, width:1200, height: 800};
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);


    // check if context exist
    if (elem.getContext) {

        var array = [];

        array.push(new Shape(20, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(20, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(20, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(80, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(80, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(80, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(140, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(140, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
        array.push(new Shape(140, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
        //context = elem.getContext('2d');
    }

    //function draw (){
    // context.fillStyle = 'red'; 
    //context.fillRect(container.x, container.y, container.width, container,height);
    //}

    setInterval(function () {

        /// clear canvas for each frame
        //context.clearRect(0, 0, context.elem.width, context.elem.height);

        /// iterate object array and move all objects
        for (var i = 0, oRec; oRec = array[i]; i++) {
            // context.clearRect(0, 0, context.elem.width, context.elem.height);

            oRec.x++; /// update each object's position
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = oRec.fill;
            context.fillRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);
            context.fill();

        }
    }, 40);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this instead as there is no `elem` property on context:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
```

or use `elem` directly (which is a tad faster and also shorter to write):

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);
```

**[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/wxVHK/)**

The `clearRect()` clears *everything* on canvas including filled background (a canvas element is transparent by default and will be in initial state or becoming again when using `clearRect()`).

Either replace `clearRect()` with `fillRect()` using a black `fillStyle` or set a CSS background for the element (the latter won't be saved together with any image if that is needed, ie. `toDataURL()`).

With black background:

**[Fiddle 2 using CSS background](http://jsfiddle.net/wxVHK/1/)**

**[Fiddle 3 using fillRect instead of clearRect](http://jsfiddle.net/wxVHK/2/)**

You can optimize `fillRect()` further (as it is slower than `clearRect()`) by only clearing the boxes (remember to add a pixel on each side for anti-aliased pixels).

Comment: it draws me only one moving rectangle of 9 rectangles! Also background which is black becomes white...@Ken

Comment: @user3247903 I added a fiddle with a few other corrections. Yes, the clearRect clears *everything* so instead you can use fillRect() with a black fillStyle or set a CSS background to the canvas element, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wxVHK/1/

Comment: I added context.clearRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, elem.width, elem.height); it works, but still background is white not black ....@Ken

Comment: @user3247903 please see my comment + answer which explains what happens.

Comment: Thank you. The second version works with fillRect() :)